# How to extract specific attribute from core date store

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, uiimageview, nsfetchrequest

I'm executing a fetch request with sort descriptor to populate a mutable array as follows:

```
NSFetchRequest *requestA = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"YearPhoto" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[requestA setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[requestA setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[sortDescriptor release];
[sortDescriptors release];

NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResultsA = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:requestA error:&error] mutableCopy];
if (mutableFetchResultsA == nil) {

}
[self setImageArray:mutableFetchResultsA];
[mutableFetchResultsA release];
[requestA release];
```

I need to extract the attribute of YearPhoto,  friendsPhoto (UIImage ~60KB stored in core data store) to setImageArray for use here in an animation within a UIImageView.....

```
 self.theImageView.animationImages = [NSMutableArray initWithArray:imageArray];
```

I have also tried:

```
self.theImageView.animationImages = [NSArray initWithObjects:yearPhoto.friendsPhoto, nil];
```

I can't work it out. Checked docs but they are not very clear on this specific problem

Anyone see the error in my ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that "Year Photo" is being returned as an Entity you should take the object out of the mutableFetchResultsA and then lookup the friendsPhoto from that object.  I'm also not sure what you datatypes are but I'm assuming friendsPhoto is of same type as ImageArray.  It would be something like this:

```
YearPhoto* photo = [mutableFetchResultsA objectAtIndex:0];
[self setImageArray:photo.friendsPhoto];
```

Comment: chamberlain, thanks for commenting! This fails :( YearPhoto is an entity. Image Array is an array,    photo.friends photo returns a single UIImage, not an array of UIImages which is what I need to work out. I cant work out how to extract the attribute friendsPhoto from the parent entity YearPhoto, add the extracted images  to a mutableArray then assign that mutable array to the " self.theImageView.animationImages = " its hurting my brain. I have been through 20 or more permutations of the code posted and no cigar :(

Comment: Can you break it down to which step is failing.  Have you verified that you can extract the YearPhoto object from the fetch results?

Comment: I fixed the issue. I had to add a add the following to extract the friendsPhoto attribute (UIImage type) `self.imageArray = [mutableFetchResultsA valueForKey:@"friendsPhoto"];`  Thank you for taking the time to help, its much appriciated!